# what is the difference between hashbang and HTML5 pushState?

Tags: angularjs, pushstate, hashbang

on the angularJs official web site in ngRoute section they have mentioned two types of url supports hashbang and HTML5 pushstate.
i want to know the difference  between both hashbang and pushstate?

Comment: pushstate allows you to change the “real”, full URL displayed in the browser address bar, whereas the hashbang method only changes the hash part of the URL (since that doesn’t navigate to a different page, as changing the full address with pre-HTML5 History API methods would.)

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: I have written about HTML5Mode on multiple articles, but I think the answer in the marked duplicate has the most clear explanation.